# If you change Webalizer settings, will those new settings only apply to future months?

Tags: analytics, awstats

I am considering using Webalizer for my sites, but I'd like to verify something I am reading in the configuration/readme files first. Any help is appreciated...

If default configuration file is used, my monthly reports will show the top 30 "sites" or visitors to the website. The "All" and "Tab" reports for sites are set to "no" by default, meaning that full listings of sites/visitors are not created and thus not retained after the month is over.

So following this logic, if I should decide, for example, in July 2019 that I would like to begin creating files showing all sites/visitors, it will only apply to months from that point onward. Meaning that I would not be able to view all sites/visitors to the website from May 2019.

This is my understanding from reading the Webalizer documentation. Can anyone confirm? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you make changes to the settings, it will only affect new data going forward.   That is because Webalizer stores aggregate information from the past and only applies most new settings against web logs as it is run going forward.

However, if you keep your log files you can always run Webalizer against them with new settings.  Webalizer can be manually re-run against previous days and months with new settings.   Because of this, I recommend archiving and retaining all log files.

This is a bit advantage of a log file analysis to like Webalizer or Awsats.  Java script snippets that send data to third parties such as Google Analytics can't be re run if your filters or settings change.